# How can I stop printing the error message "Can't parse message of type because it is missing required fields" with protobuf3

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, protobuf-3

I just want to parse an instance from a string when logging something, and don't care the result.

But when I update protobuf to 3.5.0, the annoying message is always printing to the terminal (stderr):

> “Can't parse message of type because it is missing required fields”

Its fields must be required.

How can I stop printing the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Options:

- make it `optional` instead of `required`
- provide the missing data
- hook `stderr` and send it to `nul`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the protobuf library itself doesn't directly print to stderr. Instead, error messages are returned through the API like `message->InitializationErrorString()`.

So it seems it is your own code that is printing this message to stderr, or perhaps you have enabled some debug mode.

You can try to add a debugger hook to the print to see where it is coming from.